# Encoding works wrong

Tags: intellij-idea, encoding

I put the encoding UTF-8, it didn`t work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTLH8.png)

Then I tried to change on windows-1251, and then back at UTF-8, it works only 1 compilation, then the same error.

In Settings -> File Encodings I set default and UTF-8, but it didn`t help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy2il.png)

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Do no put external images on the question. This is a reference site, so we must be able to see the images together with the question, for many years. And do you expect many programmers will click a random link from a unknown person? And if you have an error, copy also the text (if help us to write the answer). So with just the text of your question it is very difficult to help. Common problem: program is UTF-8 but not the console; files are not UTF-8; source and runtime encoding are two different things (and independent); ...

Comment: Where do you see the wrong encoding? In terminal, your program, or in text editor?

Comment: In terminal, afer compiling